# Load image to JScrollPane

Tags: java, image, jscrollpane

I'm trying to create a simple map that will create a circle on a certain coordinate. I want to  use an image with it's fixed size as the map and add it to a `JScrollPane`. My problem here is that I dont know how to add a scrollable image.

Comment: JScrollPane is not work with fixed size. Plese, choose resizeable component.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need a way to display that image.  Is the image embedded in a component?

For example you draw the image in a JPanel

The JPanel can then be added to JScrollPane.  When you open your window you open it to the size you want and the scrollbars will be there.

Answer (score 1):

Add your image to a `JLabel`, then add that `JLabel` to your `JScrollPane`. If the size of the image is greater than the size of your `JScrollPane`, the scrollbars will appear. For example:

```
final Image image = ...
final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
container.add(scroll, ...);
```